# how to choose Foreign Key Options for better database

Tags: mysql

The condition Is like this
I have customer table

```
id_cus ---> PK
name
address
phone
```

I have Transaction table

```
no_trans ---> PK
id_cus ---> FK
datetime
payment
```

So which best solution ON DELETE Foreign key options for transaction table ?

Comment: There's not a standard best solution. It depends on what you need and what you are doing and the design of your DB.

Comment: oke asumtion that I need table transaction for report.. I think still need di_cus ..

Answer (score 0):

There's no such thing as a best option for ON DELETE. It depends on what u need it for. These are your options:

CASCADE: Delete the row from the parent table, and automatically delete or update the matching rows in the child table.

SET NULL: Delete the row from the parent table, and set the foreign key column or columns in the child table to NULL. If u specify a SET NULL action, make sure that u haven't declared the columns in the child table as NOT NULL.

RESTRICT: Rejects the delete operation for the parent table. RESTRICT is the same as omitting the ON DELETE clause.

The default action for ON DELETE is always 'RESTRICT'.

(https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html)

Hope this helps!

Comment: if i use transact table for report ?.. better i use restrict?

Comment: @KhabibbMubarakk For a report, i would indeed use restrict, so even if the cild gets deleted, u still have the reports with valid information.